# Service is not running when app clear from background in Nougat (version 25) event hough I used startforegound notification

Tags: android, service, location

As I want to calculate the distance for every two mins using googleapiclient locations in service.

**In version 25(nougat Service is not working when clear app from cache)**

I started the service in activity and gives start_sticky in start command, without notification also it should work right? below oreo versions.

For oreo versions i added the startforeground notification so is working in oreo version even-though app clear from background but in nougat same code is not working with or without notification, when I clear app from background service is not running .Please help me.

Below version>25 is working without notification, when app clear from cache also, service is running.But in Version 25 i don't know why service is not running when clear form cache.Please someone help me.

Service code:

```
 public class ForegroundLocationService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    Double mlastlocationlat,mlastlocationlong,mcurrentlocationlat,mcurrentlocationlong;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,startdistance_preference;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    float f_TotDist ;
    int timercount;
    Database database;
    private static final String TAG = ForegroundLocationService.class.getSimpleName();

    // the notification id for the foreground notification
    public static final int GPS_NOTIFICATION = 1;

    // the interval in seconds that gps updates are requested
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 15;

    // is this service currently running in the foreground?
    private boolean isForeground = false;

    // the google api client
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    // the wakelock used to keep the app alive while the screen is off
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("KS", "oncreate " );

        // create google api client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // get a wakelock from the power manager
        final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        Log.i("KS", "oncreate wakeLock"+wakeLock );

        database=new Database(this);

        // this.deleteDatabase("EmployeeDatabase.db");

        database.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("KS", "onstartcommand " );

        if (!isForeground) {

            Log.i("KS", "Starting the isForeground" + isForeground);

        startForeground(ForegroundLocationService.GPS_NOTIFICATION,
                  notifyUserThatLocationServiceStarted());
            isForeground = true;
            Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);

            // connect to google api client
            googleApiClient.connect();

            // acquire wakelock
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.i("KS", "ondestroy the " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());

     stopForeground(true);
        isForeground = false;

        // disconnect from google api client
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);

        // release wakelock if it is held
        if (null != wakeLock && wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            Log.i("KS", "if destroy" + wakeLock);

            wakeLock.release();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
        Log.i("KS", "getLocationRequest " );

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        // we always want the highest accuracy
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // we want to make sure that we get an updated location at the specified interval
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);

        // this sets the fastest interval that the app can receive updates from other apps accessing
        // the location service. for example, if Google Maps is running in the background
        // we can update our location from what it sees every five seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS));

        return locationRequest;
    }

    private Notification notifyUserThatLocationServiceStarted() {
        Log.i("KS", "notifyUserThatLocationServiceStarted " );

        // pop up a notification that the location service is running
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.getspot_logo)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.foreground_location_service))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.service_is_running))
                 .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        final Notification notification;

String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";
        Notification notification1= null;
        // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //  builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID

            // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
            notification1 = new Notification.Builder(this)

                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)

                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.foreground_location_service))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.service_is_running))
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)


                    .build();

            notification=notification1;
        }
        else
        {
            notification=builder.build();;

        }



        return notification;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("KS", "onConnected " );

        try {

            // request location updates from the fused location provider
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    googleApiClient, getLocationRequest(), this);

        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while requesting location updates", securityException);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Google API Client suspended.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google API Client.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("KS", "onLocationChanged: " + location.toString());
        startdistance_preference = getSharedPreferences("startLessonPref",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefer", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();



        editor.putString("dest_Lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        editor.putString("dest_Long", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

        editor.putString("Lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        editor.putString("Long", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

        Log.e("RS","shared--" + sharedPreferences.getString("mlastlocationlat", null));


        if(sharedPreferences.getString("mlastlocationlat", null)==null && sharedPreferences.getString("mlastlocationlong", null)==null && sharedPreferences.getString("mcurrentlocationlat", null)==null && sharedPreferences.getString("mcurrentlocationlong", null)==null)
        {


            editor.putString("mlastlocationlat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            editor.putString("mlastlocationlong", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

            editor.putString("mcurrentlocationlat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            editor.putString("mcurrentlocationlong", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

            mlastlocationlat=location.getLatitude();

            mlastlocationlong=location.getLongitude();

            mcurrentlocationlat=location.getLatitude();

            mcurrentlocationlong=location.getLongitude();
            Log.e("RS","mlastlocationlat" + mlastlocationlat);
            Log.e("RS","mlastlocationlong" + mlastlocationlong);
            Log.e("RS","mcurrentlocationlat" + mcurrentlocationlat);
            Log.e("RS","mcurrentlocationlong" + mcurrentlocationlong);


        }
        else
        {
            mlastlocationlat= Double.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString("mcurrentlocationlat", null));
            mlastlocationlong=Double.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString("mcurrentlocationlong", null));
            ;
            mcurrentlocationlat=location.getLatitude();
            mcurrentlocationlong=location.getLongitude();

            editor.putString("mlastlocationlat", String.valueOf(mcurrentlocationlat));
            editor.putString("mlastlocationlong", String.valueOf(mcurrentlocationlong));

            editor.putString("mcurrentlocationlat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            editor.putString("mcurrentlocationlong", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

               /* mcurrentlocationlat=Double.valueOf(String.format("%.4f", location.getLatitude()));
                mcurrentlocationlong=Double.valueOf(String.format("%.4f", location.getLongitude()));
               */ Log.e("RS","else--mlastlocationlat" + mlastlocationlat);
            Log.e("RS","else-mlastlocationlong" + mlastlocationlong);
            Log.e("RS","else-mcurrentlocationlat--" + mcurrentlocationlat);
            Log.e("RS","else-mcurrentlocationlong--" + mcurrentlocationlong);

        }
        editor.commit();
        Float dist = distanceCal(mlastlocationlat, mlastlocationlong,mcurrentlocationlat, mcurrentlocationlong);

    }
    private float distanceCal(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {


        Location loc1 = new Location("");
        loc1.setLatitude(lat1);
        loc1.setLongitude(lon1);

        Location loc2 = new Location("");
        loc2.setLatitude(lat2);
        loc2.setLongitude(lon2);

        float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
        float distanceinmeter= Float.parseFloat(String.format("%.2f", distanceInMeters));
        Log.e("RS--first--","-distanceInMeters-" +distanceInMeters);

        Log.e("RS---#####-1-" + lat1, "--" + lon1);
        Log.e("RS---#####-2-" + lat2, "--" + lon2);

        startdistance_preference = getSharedPreferences("startLessonPref",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        f_TotDist = startdistance_preference.getFloat("str_TotalDist", 0);
        Log.e("RS","-f_TotDist-first-" +f_TotDist);
        timercount = Integer.parseInt(startdistance_preference.getString("timerstart", null));

        database.insertData(String.valueOf(timercount),mcurrentlocationlat,mcurrentlocationlong,f_TotDist);

        // startLesson_preference = getSharedPreferences("startLessonPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        f_TotDist+=(distanceinmeter);
        timercount=timercount+3;
        Log.e("RS","-f_TotDist--if-" +f_TotDist);


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = startdistance_preference.edit();


        editor1.putFloat("str_TotalDist", (float) f_TotDist);

        editor1.putString("timerstart", String.valueOf(timercount));
        editor1.commit();



        return distanceInMeters;
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
public class SampleBackgroundServices extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {


    // the identifier for the permissions request
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID = 1999;
    SharedPreferences  startdistance_preference;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    Timer timer,timer1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Used in checking for runtime permissions.
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    ListView listView;
    // A reference to the service used to get location updates.
    private LocationUpdatesService mService = null;
    Database database;
    // Tracks the bound state of the service.
    private boolean mBound = false;
    TextView total_distance;
    // UI elements.
    private Button mRequestLocationUpdatesButton;
    private Button mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.back_services);

        mRequestLocationUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_location_updates_button);
        mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_location_updates_button);

        mRequestLocationUpdatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForegroundLocationService.class));

                startdistance_preference = getSharedPreferences("startLessonPref",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = startdistance_preference.edit();


                editor1.putFloat("str_TotalDist", (float) 0.0);

                editor1.putString("timerstart",  "0");
                editor1.commit();


                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefer", MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();



                editor.putString("mcurrentlocationlong", null);
                editor.putString("mcurrentlocationlat", null);
                editor.putString("mlastlocationlat", null);
                editor.putString("mlastlocationlong", null);

                editor.commit();


            }
        });

        mRemoveLocationUpdatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startdistance_preference = getSharedPreferences("startLessonPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                float f_TotDist = startdistance_preference.getFloat("str_TotalDist", 0);
                Log.e("RS","-runnin--f_TotDist-first-" +f_TotDist);
                total_distance.setText("Total distance"+f_TotDist/   1000+"km");

                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForegroundLocationService.class));


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {



        super.onResume();
    }



}
```

Note:I don't know how to solve this issue in nougat ,please give solution to me.Oreo version only gets stopped so we use notification,in nougat also now problem.

Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.getspot.getspot">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/getspot_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".background_services.ForegroundLocationService"
            android:enabled="true" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please someone help me to fix my issues in nougat version .

Comment: am also facing the same issue , Please let me know how you have resolved .

Answer (score 0):

In Android 7.0 (API level 25), Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background services & executions Limits by android. Because of app runs in the background, it consumes some of the device's limited resources, like RAM. [more details](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

**Migration Guide**

By default, these changes only affect apps that target Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher. However, users can enable these restrictions for any app from the Settings screen, even if the app targets an API level lower than 26. You may need to update your app to comply with the new limitations.

Check to see how your app uses services. If your app relies on services that run in the background while your app is idle, you will need to replace them. Possible solutions include:

If your app needs to create a foreground service while the app is in the background, use the ***startForegroundService()*** method instead of ***startService().***
If the service is noticeable by the user, make it a foreground service. For example, a service that plays audio should always be a foreground service. Create the service using the ***startForegroundService()*** method instead of ***startService()***.
Find a way to duplicate the service's functionality with a scheduled job. If the service is not doing something immediately noticeable to the user, you should generally be able to use a scheduled job instead.
Use FCM to selectively wake your application up when network events occur, rather than polling in the background.
Defer background work until the application is naturally in the foreground.
Review the broadcast receivers defined in your app's manifest. If your manifest declares a receiver for an implicit broadcast, you must replace it. Possible solutions include:

Create the receiver at runtime by calling ***Context.registerReceiver(),*** instead of declaring the receiver in the manifest.
Use a scheduled job to check for the condition that would have triggered the implicit broadcast.